# How to change font to Zapfino

Tags: fonts, fontspec

I am trying to change the font in an article I have created to "Zapfino".  Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

With XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Zapfino}

\begin{document}

text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info, however, I'm using overleaf and it told me that it couldn't use that package because:                                                                  ! Fatal fontspec error: "cannot-use-pdftex"
! 
! The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX.
! 
! You must change your typesetting engine to, e.g., "xelatex" or
! "lualatex"instead of plain "latex" or "pdflatex".

Comment: @Brad You can change the engine in the overleaf settings on the left hand side of the code

Comment: Thanks again.  This time when i compiled using xetex it timed out, with luatex it wiped out everything except the things in "math mode"

Comment: @Brad - Select XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, not XeTeX or LuaTeX, as the typesetting engine.

Comment: @Brad Works if the font is uploaded to overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/read/pdbftyrdvnmc